# Python: does gzip write to disk when opening a file for read?

Tags: python, gzip

I am writing a program that reads .gz archived log files from an SD card. If I open a .gz archive for reading using the gzip library, will it write a temporary copy to the SD card (I don't want it to), or does it decompress the file in RAM?

Comment: The data is decompressed in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show how exactly you're doing it, but if you are using `gzip.open()` and `read()`, then there are no temporary files. It is decompressed in memory.